# Insert multiple events to google calander

Tags: reactjs, google-calendar-api, google-api-js-client

I need to insert 120 event at once from a user to google calander
I have React app, and from it it's create 120 copies of same reminder in a 120 different dates.

I want to add them to the calander and I using `import { gapi } from 'gapi-script'`

I try to send the event individually like this:

```
var event = {
            'summary':  nameValue.toString(),
            'description': ReminderTextValues.toString(),
            'start': {
              'date': ISODateString(javasScriptDate)
            },
            'end': {
              'date': ISODateString(NextDate)
            },
            'reminders': {
              'useDefault': false,
              'overrides': [
                {'method': "email", 'minutes': 24 * 60},
                {'method': "popup", 'minutes': 30}
              ]
            }
          }


         var request = gapi.client.calendar.events.insert({
            'calendarId': 'primary',
            'resource': event,
          })

          request.execute(event => {
            console.log("Executed:", event)
          })
```

and even that I have only 100 from the 120 event that return `403` (which is a different problem) in the calander I see that only 1 actually got added.

I also try to use `batch` like this:

```
// we will submit all the request in a 1 batch
        var batch = gapi.client.newBatch();

        // We will save the eevnt for the next 120 years
        for (var startYear = HebrewDateEnteredByTheUser.year; startYear< (HebrewDateEnteredByTheUser.year+120); startYear++ )
        {

          // JS date 
          const javasScriptDate = new Date(day, month, startYear).addHours(1);
          const NextDate = javasScriptDate.addHours(22);

          // Google event
          var event = {
            'summary':  nameValue.toString(),
            'description': ReminderTextValues.toString(),
            'start': {
              'date': ISODateString(javasScriptDate)
            },
            'end': {
              'date': ISODateString(NextDate)
            },
            'reminders': {
              'useDefault': false,
              'overrides': [
                {'method': "email", 'minutes': 24 * 60},
                {'method': "popup", 'minutes': 30}
              ]
            }
          }

          batch.add(gapi.client.calendar.events.insert({
            'calendarId': 'primary',
            'resource': event,
          }));
```

and then after a loop to run this:

```
batch.then(function(){
          console.log('all jobs done!!!')
        });
```

After this I not getting any error and in the consule I see `all jobs done!!!` but when I check the calander I can find only the first 5 event, the rest are just ignored...

How can I insert 120 events at once to the google calander?

Comment: last i knew the new backing system only let you send 5 requests at a time.  Have you tried splitting it up.   Why bother with batching?  Why not just send them one at a time?

Comment: I tried, they failed...

Comment: Do you want to insert the same event on 120 days or they are different events?

Comment: @Kessy They are the same event for a different dates in 120 years

Comment: You might want to take a look at this link [here](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/errors). What message are you getting associated with the `403` error? @development

Answer (score 0):

Your symptoms are consistent with a "403 rate limit exceeded" error.
You will need to throttle your requests. The first 20 are usually OK, but after that you will need to slow down to approximately one request every 1.5 seconds. Do not use Batch because a) it's deprecated and b) it makes the problem worse.

The approach I use is to place all requests on an in-memory queue (I use Array) and then have a separate routine which dequeues items at a rate of one every x seconds. Any failures are simply left on the queue and retried. My algo is a bit heuristic, in that it gradually increases the speed until it gets a 304, and then slows down to 2s intervals.

Comment: sorry no. it's tightly bound with my app. Try freelancer.com